# Delphi - Sort files based on size

Tags: sorting, delphi

I'm trying to sort a list of files based on size in Delphi 2010. 
I've recursively got all files sizes,file creation dates and file location paths but I have a problem sorting them.

My results look like this:

MB 57.682 (60483584) - 08-06-2017 15:03 - o:\Thumbs.db

MB 4.217 (4422144) - 08-06-2017 13:48 - o:\bmp\Thumbs.db

The data must be sorted descending from largest file to smallest file and the result stored to a file.

I'm using strings to format the size of files for a human readable form.

What is the correct approach in this case? 
Should I store data as csv values and then try to sort them? 
Should I use a stringlist?

This is the code that I'm using:

```
procedure FasterSubFilesList_mmg(folder, exts: string; files: TStrings);

// builds recursive list of files matching set of extensions like '.exe .txt.htm'
 function ext(filename: string): string;
  begin result:= lowercase(extractFileExt(filename));
 end;

 CONST
  SizeUnits     : ARRAY[0..8] OF PChar = ('bytes','KB','MB','GB','TB','PB','EB','ZB','YB');

FUNCTION FormatByteSize(Size : UInt64 ; Decimals : BYTE) : String; OVERLOAD;
  VAR
    I           : Cardinal;
    S           : Extended;

  BEGIN
    S:=Size;
    FOR I:=LOW(SizeUnits) TO HIGH(SizeUnits) DO BEGIN
      IF S<1024.0 THEN BEGIN
        IF I=LOW(SizeUnits) THEN Decimals:=0;
        Result:=Format('%.'+IntToStr(Decimals)+'f',[S]);
        {adaug dimensiune urmata de unitatea de masura}
        //Result:=Result+' '+StrPas(SizeUnits[I]);

        {adaug unitatea de masura urmata de dimensiune}
        Result:=StrPas(SizeUnits[I])+' '+Result;
        EXIT
      END;
      S:=S/1024.0
    END
  END;

FUNCTION FormatByteSize(Size : UInt64) : String; OVERLOAD;
  VAR
    P   : Integer;

  BEGIN
    Result:=FormatByteSize(Size,3);
    IF Size>=1024 THEN BEGIN
      P:=PRED(LastDelimiter(' ',Result));
      WHILE COPY(Result,P,1)='0' DO BEGIN
        DELETE(Result,P,1);
        DEC(P)
      END;
      IF CharInSet(Result[P],['.',',']) THEN DELETE(Result,P,1)
    END
  END;




{ functie pentru a afla dimensiunea unui fisier }
function GetFileSize_mmg(const FileName: string): Int64;
var
  fad: TWin32FileAttributeData;
begin
if not GetFileAttributesEx(PChar(FileName), GetFileExInfoStandard, @fad) then RaiseLastOSError;
  //GetFileAttributesEx(PChar(FileName), GetFileExInfoStandard, @fad);
  Int64Rec(Result).Lo := fad.nFileSizeLow;
  Int64Rec(Result).Hi := fad.nFileSizeHigh;
end;

 procedure AddFolder(dir: string);
  var F: TSearchRec;
      size:string;
      data_creare_fisier:string;
  const
   //findTypes=faArchive+faHidden+faReadOnly+faAnyFile+faDirectory;
   findTypes=faAnyFile;
  begin
   dir:= excludetrailingbackslash(dir)+'\';

   if FindFirst(dir+'*.*', findTypes, F)=0 then
   try

    repeat
     if (F.attr and faDirectory=faDirectory) then
     begin
       if (F.Name<>'.') and (F.Name<>'..') then AddFolder(dir+F.Name);

     end
     else
     if (exts='*') or (pos(ext(F.Name)+' ', exts)>0) then
     size:=FormatByteSize(GetFileSize_mmg(dir+F.name));
     shortdateformat:='dd-mm-yyyy';
     data_creare_fisier:=formatdatetime(shortdateformat+' hh:nn',filedatetodatetime(f.time));

     files.Add(size+' ('+inttostr(GetFileSize_mmg(dir+F.name))+') - '+data_creare_fisier+' - '+dir+F.Name);
     //files.Add('"'+size+'","'+inttostr(GetFileSize_mmg(dir+F.name))+'","'+data_creare_fisier+'","'+dir+F.Name+'"');
     //files.Add(inttostr(GetFileSize_mmg(dir+F.name))+' ('+size+') - '+data_creare_fisier+' - '+dir+F.Name);
    until FindNext(F)<>0;
   finally FindClose(F) end;
  end;


begin


 if (trim(exts)='') or (exts='*') or (exts='*.*') then exts:='*'
  else exts:= trim(lowercase(exts))+' ';
 files.clear;
 AddFolder(folder);
end;



procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  FilesList: TStringList;
 i:integer;
    lista_descrescatoare:Tstrings;
begin
ListBox_fisiere_de_verificat.Items.Clear;


//listbox_fisiere_de_verificat.Items.BeginUpdate;
//afiseaza_in_listbox_fisiere_ce_pot_fi_procesate('O:\','*.*',true,10,listbox_fisiere_de_verificat,false,memo_loguri);
//listbox_fisiere_de_verificat.Items.EndUpdate;
memo_loguri.lines.add(FormatDatetime('dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss', Now) +' - start listare fisiere');
FilesList:=Tstringlist.Create;
FilesList.Sorted:=true;
FilesList.Sort;



FasterSubFilesList_mmg('o:\','*.*',FilesList);

listbox_fisiere_de_verificat.items.AddStrings(FilesList);

memo_loguri.lines.add(' - total fisiere:'+inttostr(fileslist.count));
memo_loguri.lines.add(FormatDatetime('dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss', Now) +' - stop listare fisiere');

end;
```

Thank you!

Comment: It depends. If you want to keep it stored, store it (better in a lightweight database like SQLite). If you don't, sort it in a memory collection, not in visual control.

Comment: I think this question really depends on where are you storing your output, or is it just about sorting in visual controls?

Comment: I've updated my question. I need to get the data sorted and them saved into a file.

Comment: What is the problem? Sorting them? Just sort on the actual sizes (Int64 values), not on some kind of strings.In what format do you store the files and their sizes while you are recursively enumerating them? Show the code you use to collect the files and their sizes.

Comment: FWIW, "what is the best approach" is subject to opinion. Rather change your question to ask for something specific, e.g."I have data in this format, how can I sort on file size?", etc.

Comment: Why are there strings involved?

Comment: @David: my question too. The sorting should be done on the actual length, in integral (Int6 or UInt64) form.

Comment: @David,@Rudy: The strings are not the problem.I can remove them. The ideea is that I need to sort the int64data in a natural way and I don't know how to do that.

Comment: @user2858981 You don't have int64 data. You have string data. You truncate to 2GB when you call `IntToStr`. You concatenate directory to file name repeatedly. Likewise you call GetFileSize_mmg repeatedly with the same value. The code is a proper mess. My advice is to throw it away and start again, with no GUI. Come up with a proper data structure, a collection holding items containing full path to file and the file size. Sort that. Then populate your GUI.

Comment: @David: "You truncate to 2GB when you call IntToStr". I was not aware of this! Thank you for pointing this problem!

Comment: @user2858981: Then put the Int64 lengths and some other info into a very simple class, and add that to the TStringList as object associated with a string (e.g. the file name, or full path). Then you can sort the list using CustomSort.

Comment: `GetFileSize_mmg` is not needed btw. You can get the `Size` from `TSearchRec`.

Comment: @Victoria: Thanks for the observation. Indeed. I could have used the Size from the TsearchRec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that you already have your list of files in the FilesList TStringList, you can just sort them there. You can call the CustomSort method, providing a custom compare function to indicate which file is greater than another.

```
function FileGreater(FileList: TStringList; Index1: integer; Index2: integer): integer;
var IniPos1, EndPos1, IniPos2, EndPos2: integer;
    Size1, Size2: Int64; 
begin
  IniPos1 := Pos('(', FileList[Index1]) + 1;
  EndPos1 := Pos(')', FileList[Index1]) - 1;
  IniPos2 := Pos('(', FileList[Index2]) + 1;
  EndPos2 := Pos(')', FileList[Index2]) - 1;

  Size1 := StrToint64(Copy(FileList[Index1], IniPos1, EndPos1 - IniPos1));
  Size2 := StrToint64(Copy(FileList[Index2], IniPos2, EndPos2 - IniPos2));

  if Size1 = Size2 then Result := 0
  else if Size1 < Size2 then Result := -1
  else Result := 1;
end;
```

Now you just call :

```
 FileList.CustomSort(FileGreater);
```

PS : As David Heffernan says in a comment, StrToInt returns a LongInt, so it would only work for files up to 2Gb. I have updated the answer to use StrToInt64, but you will be better using a proper structure to store the data of your files instead of this quick fix.

Comment: What about TStringList.CustomSort?

Comment: I didn't know that method. Yes, it's even easier. :-). I will edit the answer. Thanks.

Comment: TStringList.CustomSort would certainly be easier and faster

Comment: But this is still not so easy. If all file sizes ae expressed in MB, then fine. But if small files are expressed in kB or even bytes, and huge files in GB etc., then that must be taken into account as well.

Comment: This fails for files of size > 2GB. It would also be so much better to bite the bullet and store the size in an integral type, and stop treating a GUI control as a data type. GUI controls are for presentation. I know you are repeating the sins of the question, but it would be better not to.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis he has between parenthesis the size expressed in bytes, so it would work for any file (up to the LongInt limit of StrToInt, as David said). Look for example at this line sample : MB 57.682 (60483584) - 08-06-2017 15:03 - o:\Thumbs.db

Comment: Thank you Marc Guillot! Your solution works well! I will update the entire code to address the file size issues reported by David Heffernan.